# Emotion roll from center to right using Android animation

Tags: android, animation, rotateanimation

I want my `ImageView` roll from center of screen to right. I use this code at the moment, but it doesn't roll the image.

```
final AnimationSet rollingIn = new AnimationSet(true);

Animation moving = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0);
moving.setDuration(5000);

rollingIn.addAnimation(moving);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
final AnimationSet rollingIn = new AnimationSet(true);
    Animation moving = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0);
    moving.setDuration(1000);
    final Animation rotating = new RotateAnimation(0, 720, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotating.setDuration(1000);

    rollingIn.addAnimation(rotating);
    rollingIn.addAnimation(moving);
```